# Making color text file using GDAL

Tags: gdal, color-ramp, gdaldem

I have an 8-bit greyscale image that I want to convert to a "heat map" based on data values (0-255), using a color ramp.  I'm aware that `gdaldem` works with color-relief, so I used the following steps from a prior post:

1. Take a raster of your choice (like SRTM as an example)
2. Create the following text file named col.txt:

   ```
    0 black
    100 blue
    200 yellow
    300 orange
    400 red
    500 white
   ```
3. On command line, run

   ```
    gdaldem color-relief N51E007.hgt col.txt out.tif
   ```

   When I do this, I get the following:

   > "ERROR 1: Unknown color : Menlo-Regular;}"

It seems it is seeing the font type, for some odd reason.  [image]

Comment: I tested it with my N51E007.hgt and your col.txt and works fine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WA2sC.png.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably completely redundant now but it seems like you have additional information in your col.txt file. Perhaps the editor you used specified styling information.